# Oracle SQL to return multiple values from another table/rows into single field in another table

Tags: database, oracle

I'm attempting to complete a Database final project where I need to create a database for a web forum. Just the DB work, not PHP/HTML/etc.

For this example, we are hard coding a user into the code, since we're not using variables. For my example, I'll use User_ID 2.
I'm stuck on a requirement. I need to create a view that lists the users' profile and their interests. So, field names like, Username, F_Name, L_Name, etc.
My problem is, the "Interests" for the users are stored in another table. I need a view that will essentially display as below:

```
Users.Username   Users.F_Name   Users.L_Name   Users.Joined (VARCHAR2)   Users.Signature   Users.Website   INTERESTS
```

I'd like it to return such as:

```
"JSmith" "John", "Smith", "1/1/2016", "SigHere", "www.example.com, "Music, Movies, Tech" With the entire list of interests all within one field of the view.
```

The interest table looks as follows:

```
INTEREST_ID    USER_ID CATEGORY_ID
  1              2       1
  2              2       2
  3              2       3
  4              3       1
  5              3       2
  6              4       2
  7              5       1
  8              5       2
  9              5       3
```

Categories table is:

```
CATEGORY_ID   NAME       DESCRIPTION
  1           Music          All about them Jamz!
  2           Electronics    Tech Talk
  3           Movies         The BIG screen
```

Users table is:

```
User_ID     Integer         NOT NULL,
Username    VARCHAR2(60)    NOT NULL,
Password    VARCHAR2(60),
Email       VARCHAR2(255),
F_Name      VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
L_Name      VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
Joined      VARCHAR2(10),
Level_ID    INTEGER         NOT NULL,
Signature   VARCHAR2(255),
Website     VARCHAR2(60)
```

CREATE TABLE Users

```
User_ID     Integer         NOT NULL,
Username    VARCHAR2(60)    NOT NULL,
Password    VARCHAR2(60),
Email       VARCHAR2(255),
F_Name      VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
L_Name      VARCHAR2(20)    NOT NULL,
Joined      VARCHAR2(10),
Level_ID    INTEGER         NOT NULL,
Signature   VARCHAR2(255),
Website     VARCHAR2(60)
```

I tried this command, but it returned "single-row subquery returns more than one row" when I tried to select * from it, which I understand why. Just can't figure out how to get it to do what I'd like. Is it even possible?

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW Profile AS
SELECT Users.Username, Users.F_Name, Users.L_Name, Users.Joined, Users.Website, 
(SELECT UserInterested.Category_ID FROM UserInterested) AS InterestList
FROM Users
WHERE Users.User_ID = 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at the listagg() function at http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515.  You will need to join on the interests table for both users.user_id = interests.user_id (Left join if you want to display the user even if he is "uninterested") and interests.category_id = categories.category_id.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up not using a subquery for the project. The view repeated the username a bunch of times, but the instructor said that's fine (the programmer would strip it).
However, it has been bugging me and I wanted to figure it out. I'll give it a shot and see what happens! Thanks!